# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier not working with ARC and IOS 4

Tags: iphone, ios4, automatic-ref-counting

I can't seem to get `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` working.

I need to build a project for IOS 4 so I can't use storyboards, but I'm using ARC.

Let's say I have 2 sections, each with 1 row.

Looking at the code below, I'm using the strong property to pass ownership, since ARC would insert the "autorelease" code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TableCellIdentifier";

     MainTableCell *cell = (MainTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

     if (cell == nil) 
     {
          self.retainedCell = [[MainTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
     }

     [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

     return cell;
}
```

However, for each row, cell is always nil (and hence a new MainTableCell is alloc'd) each time the function is called. The cell is never re-used.

This wouldn't be so much a problem except I programmatically call tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, meaning I get a newly alloc'd cell each time, rather than the existing cell.

The only method I can see is to add the cells to an NSMutableArray.

Is there something I'm missing with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` now?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I'm using the code below to get the cell. As mentioned it's creating a new cell not re-using the one that should have been already made + retained.
I don't need to invoke reloadData for all the rows, just change a specific one.

```
MainTableCell *cell = (MainTableCell *)[self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: you have only one row in each section then there will be two rows visible and I don't think that your rows goes out of view and your cells are reused.. please attach screen shot of your table view

Comment: You call this method yourself? Why are you doing that? Can you explain that a little more as it is almost definitely wrong.

Comment: It's not wrong at all. I need to have something specific done with a specific UITableViewCell and hence I need a reference to it.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore You may be right, but then my cell is being re-alloc'd when I grab it too. See edit.

Answer (score 3):

You happen to be de-queuing MainTableCell, and then you proceed to check if it is nil, at which point you use a completely different var to alloc a table cell.  What the heck?  Try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TableCellIdentifier";
    MainTableCell *cell = (MainTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[MainTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: If someone could format this properly, I'd be much obliged (gall durn mobile SO).

Comment: I feel your pain... 90% of my answers are done via mobile. Links are also fun.

Comment: Unfortunately as I mentioned the property is to try retain the variable. Your code above was the first thing I'd tried (its quite basic) but didn't work.

Comment: What about using only the property then?

Comment: That didn't work either. The cell is still re-created and not dequeued.